# Can I just remove data in localStorage by its key?

Tags: html, local-storage

I am learning about HTML5 these days.

Here comes trouble when I want to remove just one of the data in the localStorage.

I know a method called `clear()` to remove anything, but what can I do if I just remove one of the data by its key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `delete window.localStorage["foo"]` not work for you for some reason?

Comment: I was told that there's a method called localStorage.remove('key') but don't know this method, it's work in my Chrome,thanks

Comment: Oh, I get the point. As per the [IDL](http://code.google.com/codesearch#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/WebCore/storage/Storage.idl), you have the `removeItem(key)` method.

Comment: I found the `remove(key)` method in this page[link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_storage.htm)

Comment: As per the [specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#the-storage-interface), there is only `removeItem()`. I believe your reference link is outdated (it usually takes a while for APIs to stabilize.)

Comment: Thanks anyway Alex, i'm about to see those two links you've just given

Comment: I am not sure if this makes sense, "foo" was retrieved via I/O. deleting the item in memory does not delete the item on disk? Local-storage is read from disk.

Answer (score 64):

```
sessionStorage.removeItem('UserName');
localStorage.removeItem('UserName');
```